# Loading Non cached webview in android app

Tags: android, html, css, webview, header

I have a HTML template file which is used at multiple places one of them is it is used to get loaded as a webview in few android apps, How can I make sure everytime webview is loaded it loads the most recent version(No cache) without making any changes in app settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);     
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Check out more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

Answer (score 1):

When WebView finishes a page everytime, clear the cache. Something like this in your WebViewClient:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
   view.clearCache(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Masum for answering this, but my problem is I can only control the content of HTML file I have no control over the webview client and its settings, Is there anything that I can add in HTML template which will override the webview cache settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just after creating your `WebView`, before loading any pages, you can clear the cache.

```
browser.clearCache(true);
```

and one other way is to Override `onPageFinished()` which is called each time a page gets loaded, so you could clear cache in it.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    view.clearCache(true);
}
```